# Match Function to Apps Script for Finding Closest but Less Than Date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of dates. I have a specific date "Search Date". I want to find the date in the array that is closest to but less than the Search Date and return the index of that date in the array.

**Example:** Suppose the array of dates is `[8/1/21, 8/5/22, 8/5/23]`, indexed `1,2,3` for sake of example. Suppose my Search date is `9/17/22`. The function should find the date `8/5/22` and return the index `2`.

In Google Sheets, this is simply the match function:
[image]

How do I do this (and most efficiently) in Apps Script? The `IndexOf()` function seems to return only an exact match, which does not work in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

The idea would be to compare each date in the array with the search date and select the **absolute minimum difference** which will be the closest date to the search date:

```
const checkDif = checkDates.map(d=>searchDate - d).filter(v=>v>0);
const minIndex = checkDif.indexOf(Math.min(...checkDif))+1;
```

- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is used to calculate the difference between the dates for every date in the input array.
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is used to select only the positive differences (namely the dates that are smaller than the search date).
- [Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) is used to calculate the minimum value of the array of the positive differences, therefore the closest date that is less than the search date.
- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is used to calculate the index of that minimum value.

We do `+1` because array indexes in `JavaScript` start from `0` but it seems you want them to start from `1`.

### Solution:

See comments for further explanation and in case you want to change the ranges or the name of the sheet.

```
function closestDate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // name of the sheet
  const searchDate = sh.getRange("B4").getValue(); // search date
  const checkDates = sh.getRange("B1:D1").getValues().flat(); // input range
  const checkDif = checkDates.map(d=>searchDate - d).filter(v=>v>0);
  const minIndex = checkDif.indexOf(Math.min(...checkDif))+1;
  console.log(minIndex); // 2
  sh.getRange("B5").setValue(minIndex); // return the result to B5
}
```

**Example that works with the code snippet:**

[image]

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful. Thank you. Your code and explanation are amazing. I have one follow up question. My goal is to get the index of the original array of dates. Your code above happens to work because I listed the dates in increasing order, from the oldest to newest date. However, if the dates in the array were in random order, the code you gave will give the index of the **filtered** array of positive values. Therefore it will be the wrong index if the dates are out of order. Do you see a way to modify what you wrote to get the  minimum **positive** value of your `checkDif` array?

Comment: @KimHopkins It does not matter the order of the dates. The code compares the differences and then finds the minimum positive value. It does not matter the position in this step because the index is calculated by the indexof method. So the order does not matter. If you feel otherwise, edit your question and include an example that you think the code does not work. Also consider accepting and upvoting the answer when it will solve the issue

Comment: Ok. I thought since the code filtered for positive differences, that filter would create a new array, and so the index would be of the new array vs the original array. In the case, for example, that the dates were in reverse chronological, I thought it would return the wrong index because of this. Thank you again. I can't upvote because I'm new but I greatly appreciate your write-up.